# $order->getCustomerName() returned ?? for unicode customer name

Tags: customer, sales-order, magento-ee

Under Magento EE 1.14, I have unicode characters in the customer name, the following code does return correct name in unicode for the first time:

```
$order  = Mage::getSingleton("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId(166690006338);
$order->getCustomerName();
```

however, after I add the following db close connection lines, the return becomes malformed ??. Any clue for how to fix the problem?

```
$db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('sales_read');
$db->closeConnection();
```

// the return becomes malformed ?? after the closeConnection, however, any non Unicode characters still shows correctly

```
$order  = Mage::getSingleton("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId(166690006338);
$order->getCustomerName();
```